# MVC with AngularJS and node js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, model-view-controller

I have been wondering whether this combination of technologies would work. I can implement a modular web application with MVC, EF, and utilize AngularJs if I would want to play around with the technology to implement sort of a mini SPA. I would like to extend my knowledge a bit further, and I was wondering whether I could utilize node.js instead of EF for relational database communication. Can I intermingle MVC back end with AngularJs for front end (mixed with MVC), and node.js for database communications

Comment: When you say "MVC" are you referring to ASP.NET MVC? "MVC" all by itself is a software architectural pattern, not a specific technology.

Comment: your question is all over the map.  node.js isn't a replacement for Entity Framework.....

Comment: So, what you are suggesting is technically possible, but highly impractical. It would require your server to be running two instances of a server-side framework and to be configured to listen on different ports for each one, and then synchronize data/logic between the two. TLDR; don't do this.

Comment: I know, this is a generic question, can I intermingle those three technologies: ASP.NET MVC, AngularJs, and node.js. This is for studying purposes. Is it possible?

Comment: it may be a generic question, but it actually is **too** generic.  You *specifically* ask if you can use node.js instead of EF for database communication, but that would imply that you never expect Asp.Net MVC to ever talk to a database, and if that's the case, then what's the point of using that technology?

Comment: in other words, in your list of different technology pieces, it is MVC and node.js that are overlapped, not EF and node.js.  So why you would want to use the two technologies that overlap at the same time is confusing.

Comment: I still would talk to database, but was wondering whether I can utilize node.js instead of EF, as I do right now

Comment: @lucas Which goes back to Claies's original comment, which is that node.js is not a replacement for EF

Comment: so then you would want MVC to talk to node?  what database are you using that node would communicate with?

Comment: Isn't node.js for database communication, perhaps I am confused here

Comment: node.js is a server side JavaScript interpreter, it is not a Database ORM (Object Relational Mapper) like EF.

Comment: @lucas No, node.js is a serve for writing web applications. You can do routing, DB calls, server-side validation logic, HTTP request handling, etc.

Comment: I thought node.js could be used instead of EF, and in that case ASP.NET MVC controller would talk to node.js instead of EF. Perhaps that is not the case

Comment: gotcha, so node.js can be used instead of ASP.NET MVC then? What technology node.js would use for database communication then?

Comment: @lucas Yes, that is semi-correct - technically node would be a replacement for IIS, which is the server that ASP.NET runs on, but any server-side code to handle http requests, DB calls, etc. running on node.js would be a replacement for ASP.NET. And again, MVC is simply an architecture.

Comment: gotcha, thanks for clarification

Comment: @lucas As for RDBMS for node.js, a quick google search will get you some common results, but you can also check out the rdbms keyword on the npm site. Some examples include MySQL, postgreSQL, etc. link is here: https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/rdbms -- see also this link for MySQL for node article: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-node-mysql-javascript-client/

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Yes, technically, but it would be very bad practice.

ASP.NET's MVC does nearly everything server-side. This means that views are built within the server and sent to the user. The controller is also server side.

With AngularJS, this paradigm is flipped on its head. The controller and view are both client side. The server sends the user all of the views and controllers at once, and then from then on only serves data. This is very attractive for single-page applications, and sites that want to exchange data, but not have to constantly send a new view. NodeJS is a popular architecture to use for the server, but any server architecture will work fine with Angular.

Both systems have their pros and cons, but there is no sane reason I can think of to use them together. You can certainly use ASP.NET as the server/model for an AngularJS application, but I'd discourage you from using APT.NET **MVC** with Angular.

Comment: gotcha, this is only for studying purposes, not necessarily for practicality. I develop application with meny technologies combined, and I did not touch node.js just yet, just was wondering whether it is possible, so I can jump into studying it as well (combining it with the technoglies I already know). thanks

Comment: I 100% agree with everything here except "I'd discourage you from using ASP.NET MVC with Angular". We use Angular on top of ASP.NET MVC in production and it works great. You can still utilize the benefits of the MVC framework, but also leverage the power of Angular. A great example of this is passing a model or viewbag data to a view, and then injecting that into your Angular controller.

Comment: @mhodges Quite interesting! I can see how that could work well.

Comment: Yes, with AngularJS you can implement mini SPA wit ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @LucasWatson Angular and Razor also play nicely together in that you can use a razor HTML helper for say, building a dropdown list from viewbag data, but then use any ng-* attributes on that as well and it will do everything you need from the Angular side

Comment: agreed, it might simplify front end dev for sure, even with ASP.NET MVC

Comment: @lucas For more complex stuff yes, but if you're just starting to learn these frameworks and paradigms, you really should stick with one.

Comment: I have extensive knowledge with many .NET technologies, just wanted to intermingle and learn one new technology that is becoming popular nowadays, and that is node.js. But seems it seems it cannot be used with ASP.NET MVC, there is probably not sense for me to jump into that technology, at least not right now. Even though AngularJS is not important with ASP.NET MVC, I am planning to use that one just for the sake of learning something new. Also, AngularJS is already so popular, it important to learn that client tech to stay not too behind, thanks